# Understanding ANNs as mathematical models

Tags: neural-networks, backpropagation

Consider the following feed forward neural network with inputs $x_1$, $x_2$ and output $y$ and with inflowing weights $w_j$ ($j$ for each row of arrows) for the hidden layer and $u_j$ for the output layer and an activation function $h(x)$ and no bias neurons:

[image]

Can one mathematically model this as:
$y=h( $$u_1$$h(w_1x_1+w_4x_2)$+$u_2$$h(w_2x_1+w_5x_2)$+$u_3$$h(w_3x_1+w_6x_2)$)
and then use that expression after training the neural network for regression (plugging the example directly into the expression to find $y$)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, that expression is right. It represents the feedforward propagation.

Just in case it helps, here is a way of writing that expression with matrix notation (it would be more worthy as the ANN size grows):

$$y = h\left[\begin{pmatrix}
u_1 & u_2 & u_3
\end{pmatrix} h\left[ \begin{pmatrix}
w_1 & w_4 \\
w_2 & w_5 \\
w_3 & w_6 \\
\end{pmatrix} \begin{pmatrix}
x_1 \\
x_2
\end{pmatrix} \right] \right]
$$

Comment: OP seems to say $u_i$ are the weights of output layer

Comment: My bad, thanks for noticing, then I'm wrong and @Essam is correct. In a while I will delete my response to not confuse anyone.

Comment: You can convert your answer into a positive one if you want.